# How can I left join with aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `rating` and `business`.

`rating` table:

```
bussId    userId     rating
----------------------------
  5          454       3
  8          684       5
  8          102       2
```

and `business` table:

```
bussId     businessName
-----------------------
   5           name1
   8           name2
```

I want to get the `bussName` and it's rating with this query:

```
SELECT business.businessName,
 COUNT(rating.rating) as ratingCount,
 SUM(rating.rating)as ratingSum
FROM business 
LEFT JOIN (business.bussId = rating.bussId) 
WHERE 1
```

Unfortunately I got just one row when I use the aggregate function? Why does this happen?

Comment: You're not using a `Group By`; you may want to wrap `rating.rating` in a `Coalesce(rating.rating, 0)`; the `Where` clause is pointless; and is this even valid `Left Join` syntax?  I've never seen a `Left Join` done that way before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a few syntax issues.  Your `FROM` clause with the `LEFT JOIN` is missing the join to the `rating` table.  You are missing the `ON` clause for the JOIN.  And you are missing a `GROUP BY` since you are aggregating the data.  The query should be:

```
SELECT 
  business.businessName,
 COUNT(rating.rating) as ratingCount,
 SUM(rating.rating) as ratingSum
FROM business 
LEFT JOIN rating
  ON business.bussId = rating.bussId
GROUP BY business.businessName;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efe641/3). If you don't use a GROUP BY with your aggregate function, then you won't return data for each `businessName` and MySQL will select a single value to return.

**Note**: I removed the `WHERE 1` clause because it's not needed. You aren't filtering anything.